# Tkinter Does Not Appear on X Desktop

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I have a python3 tkinter script that begins by running `/usr/bin/X` and setting the `DISPLAY` environmental variable, before starting `Tk`.

There are no errors, but nothing is displayed on the screen besides a black screen and one underscore in the top left.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please show me your tkinter script that causes your problem?

Comment: I could post it, sure, but the issue is that it does not display anything at all when run on an empty X server. It works just fine when I run it on my main machine with a window manager.